# .htaccess web/ + secure directory 1and1 Webserver

Tags: apache, .htaccess, symfony

I am running symfony2.3. My .htaccess looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options -MultiViews
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
   RewriteRule ^/web/ - [L]
</IfModule>
```

I always have to enter www.example.com/web/en/. How can I get rid fo web/ ?

I also can get to files to www.example.com/composer.json. This should not happen. How can I secure it?

TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing this line

```
RewriteRule ^/web/ - [L]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^/ - [L]
```

should help with the first issue.

The second issue isn't possible if that file is used on a webpage. If a browser can access it then a user can.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the reply, but it is not fixing the issue. Thanks for the second answer.

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/$1 [QSA,L]
 </IfModule>
```

But now I have www.example.com/de/ also www.example.com/web/de/. Is there a way to have only the first was?